# Deprecation of the Basic authentic exchange online - Impact on C# implementation

Tags: c#, authentication, smtp, exchange-server, basic-authentication

After reading this article [Deprecation of the Basic authentic exchange online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online), I would like to know whether my implementation on c# using Office365 SMTP will have any impact.

Please check if the code will stop working?

**Web.Config:**
[image]

**C# Code:**

```
public void SendEmailUsingSmtp(MailMessage mail, string host, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            //send the message
            using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            SmtpSection smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");

            // Non RFC Fix - From address becomes the ReplyTo address and the Mail.From is hardcoded
            if (!mail.ReplyToList.Contains(mail.From))
                mail.ReplyToList.Add(mail.From);

            var displayName = mail.From.Address;
            mail.From = new MailAddress(smtpSection.From, displayName); ;

            smtp.Send(mail);
        }

        finally
        {   // release all the attachments
            foreach (var a in mail.Attachments) { a.Dispose(); }
        }
    }
```

I am a little confused with Basic authentication and modern authentication.

**Update 1:**

So got in touch with Microsoft support and O365 support. The code will work even after Jan 1st 2023. However it is recommended to change to the modern authentication.

Any tips please?

Comment: Can you switch to the web service form?

Answer (score 1):

System.Net.Mail doesn’t support “modern authentication”.

The OAuth2 SASL mechanism is what they mean by “modern authentication”.

If you want to use OAuth2, you’ll need to use a 3rd party SMTP client implementation such as [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) (which is the library I’ve written).